# React JS map array for infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flickr

I have a simple React App, where I fetch the Flickr Public Feed API and display it. Unfortunately it is mapping the array several times, where I can see repeated photos. The request always returns an array with 20 items with the same pictures, explaining the repetition.

Check the code below:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

import PhotoListItem from '../../components/photoListItem';
import Searchbar from '../../components/searchBar';
import ScrollButton from '../../components/scrollButton';

import '../app/index.css';

export default class PhotoApp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            photoList: [],
            searchTerm: 'cyanotype',
            items: 10,
            loadingState: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getPhotoList();
        this.onInfiniteScroll();
    }

    /* get data from Flickr public feed */
    getPhotoList = () => {
        const flickrApiPoint = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?&tags=" + this.state.searchTerm;

        try {
            $.ajax({
                url: flickrApiPoint,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: { format: "json" },
                success: function (data) {
                    this.setState({ photoList: data.items });
                }.bind(this)
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    /* code for infinite scroll */
    onInfiniteScroll = () => {
        this.refs.iScroll.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
            if (this.refs.iScroll.scrollTop + this.refs.iScroll.clientHeight >= this.refs.iScroll.scrollHeight - 20) {
                this.loadMoreItems();
            }
        });
    }

    /*  */
    displayItems = () => {
        var items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items; i++) {
            items.push(
                this.state.photoList.map((photo, index) => {
                    const author = photo.author.split(/"/)[1];
                    const authorLink = photo.description.split(/"/)[1]
                    const description = photo.description.split(/"/)[13]
                    return (
                        <PhotoListItem
                            key={index}
                            url={photo.media.m}
                            photoLink={photo.link}
                            title={photo.title}
                            author={author}
                            authorLink={authorLink}
                            description={description}
                            tags={photo.tags} />
                    )
                })
            );
        }
        return items;
    }

    /*  */
    loadMoreItems = () => {
        if (this.state.loadingState) {
            return;
        }
        this.setState({ loadingState: true });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ items: this.state.items + 10, loadingState: false });
        }, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='appContainer' ref="iScroll">
                <div className='appHeader'>
                    <h1 className='headerTitle'>Welcome to Flickr Alternative Photography Feed!</h1>
                </div>

                <div className='gridContainer'>
                    {this.displayItems()}
                </div>
                {this.state.loadingState ? <p className='loading'>Loading items...</p> : ""}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**HERE IS THE LIVE [EXAMPLE](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-glitter-j0d2y)**

The problem is around `this.displayItems()`, but how can I fix this?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `loadMoreItems` is not calling the fetch function, so nothing more is being loaded. Once you include the fetch inside also remember to manage the pagination (check the API), so when you fetch it a second time you fetch the second page.

Comment: But isn't the problem on the `this.displayItems()`? The code is always getting the entire list and not just 1 photo item when you scroll. If I just put the `<PhotoListItem/>` without `this.state.photoList.map`, the infinite scroll seems to work with the correct number of items. @Alvaro

Comment: In my opinion the state is a bit confusing, let me explain myself and see if it can help. I would have a property for the array of objects, if you need to know the length of that array simply read the `photoList.length`, no need for  the current `items`. Instead of using `displayItems`,  simply map the `photoList` directly in `render`. Add a `current_page` property in the state so you can use it later to fetch more images where you left.

Comment: Well, the idea is: Initially you have like 8 photos, you scroll and you get 8 more while fetching new photos. That is what I was trying to achieve. But for that, don't I need the for loop? @Alvaro

Comment: So do you want to fetch all photos at once and then gradually show more and more of them. Or do you want to use the API again every time the page scrolls down to load more photos ?

Comment: Which one of your ideas is considered the best practice? @Treycos

Comment: It depends on the amount of pictures you can load at once. If the api returns hundreds of them, make another request in you `loadMoreItems` functions. If there are only a couple, you can keep your current system without a huge perf impact

Comment: Okay, thanks! In this api i just receive 20 items, so I think I will keep like I have. Thank you for your detailed answer! @Treycos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by slicing your array by the amount of items you want to show within your JSX :

```
this.state.photoList.slice(0, this.state.items).map(
```

You will then have to use the callback version of `setState` to use the old values of your state and increment what you want to show :

```
this.setState(old => ({ items: old.items + 2, loadingState: false }));
```

Fully functional example (using the "full page" option is recommended) :

```js
class PhotoListItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="image-card">
        <img className="image-card__image" alt="" src={this.props.url} />
        <div className="image-card__body">
          <div className="image-title">
            <a href={this.props.photoLink}>{this.props.title}</a>
            <span className="image-author">
              {" "}
              by <a href={this.props.authorLink}>{this.props.author}</a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="image-description">
            <span className="description">Description:</span>{" "}
            {this.props.description}
          </div>
          <div className="image-tags">
            <span className="tags">Tags:</span> {this.props.tags}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class PhotoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      photoList: [],
      items: 2,
      searchTerm: "cyanotype",
      loadingState: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPhotoList();
    this.onInfiniteScroll();
  }

  /* get data from Flickr public feed */
  getPhotoList = () => {
    const flickrApiPoint =
      "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?&tags=" +
      this.state.searchTerm;

    try {
      $.ajax({
        url: flickrApiPoint,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: { format: "json" },
        success: function(data) {
          this.setState({ photoList: data.items });
        }.bind(this)
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  /* code for infinite scroll */
  onInfiniteScroll = () => {
    this.refs.iScroll.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      if (
        this.refs.iScroll.scrollTop + this.refs.iScroll.clientHeight >=
        this.refs.iScroll.scrollHeight - 20
      ) {
        this.loadMoreItems();
      }
    });
  };

  /*  */
  loadMoreItems = () => {
    if (this.state.loadingState) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ loadingState: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState(old => ({ items: old.items + 2, loadingState: false }));
    }, 1000);
    this.getPhotoList();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="appContainer" ref="iScroll">
        <div className="appHeader">
          <h1 className="headerTitle">
            Welcome to Flickr Alternative Photography Feed!
          </h1>
        </div>

        <div className="gridContainer">
          {this.state.photoList.slice(0, this.state.items).map((photo, index) => {
            const author = photo.author.split(/"/)[1];
            const authorLink = photo.description.split(/"/)[1];
            const description = photo.description.split(/"/)[13];
            return (
              <PhotoListItem
                key={index}
                url={photo.media.m}
                photoLink={photo.link}
                title={photo.title}
                author={author}
                authorLink={authorLink}
                description={description}
                tags={photo.tags}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
        {this.state.loadingState ? (
          <p className="loading">Loading items...</p>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PhotoApp />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.appContainer {
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.appHeader {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #033666;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.headerTitle {
  color: #fff;
}

.gridContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  padding: 1rem;
  grid-gap: 1rem 1rem;
}

.loading {
  text-align: center;
  color: #033666;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .appHeader>h1 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}

a,
a:visited {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #033666;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.image-card {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: .5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  background: #fff;
}

.image-card__image {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.image-card__body {
  padding: .5rem 1rem 1rem;
}

.image-title {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding-bottom: .7rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-author {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: .8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-owner {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

.image-date-view-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image-description {
  padding-bottom: .7rem;
  font-size: .9rem;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.tags,
.description {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.image-tags {
  font-size: .8rem;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```